# I cannot read all relevant data from a web page with c# browser

Tags: c#, html, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am designing a program that reads result from orienteering competitions from web pages, extract data by means of regular expressions and makes some analysis of the data. A typical page can be seen here: http://obasen.orientering.se/winsplits/online/sv/table.asp?databaseId=67772&categoryId=2
Although the program utilizes WPF the web browser is from Windows Forms:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Width="390" Margin="0 0 20 0" Height="0">
   <wf:WebBrowser x:Name="wb" ScriptErrorsSuppressed="True" DocumentCompleted="Wb_DocumentCompleted"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

The web content is obtained by the code:

```
wb.Navigate(address);
string str = wb.DocumentText;
```

where address is the above web address.

The page source for the above page is quite messy, but if we concentrate on the second competitor (Tobias Gelius), the HTML code on the page for the second row for this competitor is:

```
<TR id="2_1" onMouseOver="highlight(2,true)" onMouseOut="highlight(2,false)">
<TD class="C1">Snättringe SK</TD>
<TD class="C37"><A title="-0.11">2.07</A></TD><TD class="C23">(1)</TD>
<TD class="C22"><A title="-0.17">5.42</A></TD><TD class="C23">(1)</TD>
<TD class="C21"><A title="+0.45">8.05</A></TD><TD class="C20">(3)</TD>
<TD class="C38"><A title="+1.31">10.53</A></TD><TD class="C39">(6)</TD>
<TD class="C38"><A title="+1.19">12.25</A></TD><TD class="C39">(5)</TD>
<TD class="C21"><A title="+1.17">17.36</A></TD><TD class="C20">(3)</TD>
<TD class="C21"><A title="+0.53">21.17</A></TD><TD class="C20">(3)</TD>
<TD class="C21"><A title="+0.39">27.21</A></TD><TD class="C20">(3)</TD>
<TD class="C21"><A title="+0.01">30.52</A></TD><TD class="C20">(2)</TD>
<TD class="C21"><A title="+0.29">36.32</A></TD><TD class="C20">(2)</TD>
<TD class="C21"><A title="+0.30">37.33</A></TD><TD class="C20">(2)</TD>
<TD class="C5">Snättringe SK</TD></TR>
```

The accumulated running time at the control points are 2.07, 5.42, 8.05 etc and the position in the race are given by the number inside the brackets (1), (1), (3), (6) etc.

When I read the page with the above code the data I obtained is the following:

```
<TR id=\"2_1\" onMouseOver=\"highlight(2,true)\" onMouseOut=\"highlight(2,false)\">
<TD class=\"C1\">Sn�ttringe SK</TD>
<TD class=\"C22\">2.07</TD>
<TD class=\"C14\">5.42</TD>
<TD class=\"C13\">8.05</TD>
<TD class=\"C23\">10.53</TD>
<TD class=\"C23\">12.25</TD>
<TD class=\"C13\">17.36</TD>
<TD class=\"C13\">21.17</TD>
<TD class=\"C13\">27.21</TD>
<TD class=\"C13\">30.52</TD>
<TD class=\"C13\">36.32</TD>
<TD class=\"C13\">37.33</TD>
<TD class=\"C4\">Sn�ttringe SK</TD></TR>
```

As can be seen a lot of information is missing, especially the position values. Is there any way to read these position values?

Comment: Just to be sure: Is there any special reason why you're using a ui control instead of HttpClient to fetch the data for processing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netstandard-2.1

Comment: hello, can you confirm if the below solution helped resolve your question, if yes please click the green tick box to mark as resolved :) –

Answer (score 0):

The question marks you see in your string output is due to the mismatch in Encoding

Converting it to UTF8 should fix that

```
  string str = wb.DocumentText;
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
  str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```